# CLANG/GCC C parser identifies static pointer as function

Tags: android, c, gcc, android-ndk, clang

I'm trying to compile `bat-hosts.c` from [Batctl 2011.2.0](http://downloads.open-mesh.org/batman/stable/sources/batctl/batctl-2011.2.0.tar.gz). However, this is an error message emitted by the CLANG 3.1 compiler from Android NDK rev. 8c:

> bat-hosts.c:41:1: error: invalid storage class specifier in function declarator

I get a similar error message from GCC 4.6 in the same NDK rev.

Line 41 reads:

```
static struct hashtable_t *host_hash = NULL;
```

This pointer to a `hashtable_t` struct (defined in `hash.h`) is declared as static outside any  function and pointed to `NULL` at declaration time, which I find to be valid.

I tried running GCC/CLANG with `std` option set to `gnu11`, `c11`, `gnu1x`, `c1x`, and `c99`.

My question is:

> Why are the compilers identifiying this pointer as a function declaration?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
`hashtable_t` struct definition:

```
struct hashtable_t {
    struct element_t **table;                   /* the hashtable itself, with the buckets */
    int elements;                               /* number of elements registered */
    int size;                                   /* size of hashtable */
    hashdata_compare_cb compare;                /* callback to a compare function.
                                                 * should compare 2 element datas for their keys,
                                                 * return 0 if same and not 0 if not same */
    hashdata_choose_cb choose;                  /* the hashfunction, should return an index based
                                                 * on the key in the data of the first argument
                                                 * and the size the second */
};
```

2nd EDIT:
Thank you all for your help. After creating an SSCCE as proposed by @JonathanLeffler, I discovered that the problem had something to to with an additional library, I forgot that I included. Sorry for wasting your time :-/

@JonathanLeffler you can post a reply if you want to and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: what is the exact definition of `hashtable_t`?

Comment: @bames53 I added the `hashtable_t` definition.

Comment: Can't reproduce on an ordinary Linux system. But that line is line 38 in the file here.

Comment: Can you enable compiler warnings (`-Wall` in gcc, similar in clang as far as I know) ?

Comment: Try looking at the preprocessor output using the `-E` option.  Maybe there's a macro in there, and maybe there's something above it in the file.

Comment: @LayZee: If this is C, then no possible definition of `hashtable_t` should be able to cause an error at this location, nor should the complete lack of a definition for `hashtable_t` cause an error.  With the exception of macros.

Comment: Even if no definition is visible, `struct hashtable_t *host_hash = NULL;` should work, it would just be a pointer to an incomplete type.

Comment: What is the typedef for `hashdata_compare_db` and `hashdata_choose_cb`?  Are there any storage classes there?  Basically, you should show us an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) that reproduces the problem.  All (but only) the necessary headers should be included.  As far as possible, it should only use standard headers.  Often, the process of creating an SSCCE will help you resolve the problem anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, after creating an SSCCE, this particular line of code is able to compile. I guess some header, etc. must be conflicting. I will try to enable one header at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

> What is the typedef for `hashdata_compare_db` and `hashdata_choose_cb`? Are there any storage classes there? Basically, you should show us an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) that reproduces the problem. All (but only) the necessary headers should be included. As far as possible, it should only use standard headers.
>
> Often, the process of creating an SSCCE will help you resolve the problem anyway.

And, indeed, it seems that creating an SSCCE has at least given you a new perspective on your problem.

Good luck with tracking down the rest of the issue.